# Django admin.site.register doesn't add my app admin

Tags: python, django

as a django newbie (I have some exprience with other python webframework like turbogears and bottle but exploring django) I'm trying to auto create the admin management for my app model

in tha main URLS.py I have:

**edit**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

and after that:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^appname/',include('appname.urls')),
                       url(r'^admin/',include(admin.site.urls))
```

notice this is in the main urls.py and not in the app urls.py

following the tutorial (which did work for me in the tutorial..) I created an 'admin.py' file in the appname folder and there:

```
from appname.models import Appname
from django.contrib import admin


class appnameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fieldsets = [various field sets and fields etc ]

admin.site.register(Appname,AppnameAdmin)
```

and in setting.py I have uncommented

```
'django.contrib.admin'
```

I don't get any error in the commandline window and the basic admin screen does appear (auth and sites)

I checked the imports in admin.py in the manage.py shell and everything seemed to work allright, I also tried commenting AppnameAdmin class out and registring just:

```
admin.site.register(Appname)
```

but that didn't work eith

I'm guessing I'm missing something obvious - I'll be glad to help with that

using django 1.4 + python 2.72

Comment: is your app in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py?

Comment: yes it is and the app it self works..

Answer (score 11):

Check all of [these](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/):

> There are seven steps in activating the Django admin site:
>
> 1. Add 'django.contrib.admin' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.
> 2. The admin has four dependencies - django.contrib.auth, django.contrib.contenttypes, django.contrib.messages and
>      django.contrib.sessions. If these applications are not in your
>      INSTALLED_APPS list, add them.
> 3. Add django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS and MessageMiddleware to
>      MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. (These are both active by default, so you only
>      need to do this if you’ve manually tweaked the settings.)
> 4. Determine which of your application’s models should be editable in the admin interface.
> 5. For each of those models, optionally create a ModelAdmin class that encapsulates the customized admin functionality and options for
>      that particular model.
> 6. Instantiate an AdminSite and tell it about each of your models and ModelAdmin classes.
> 7. Hook the AdminSite instance into your URLconf.

- Do you have all the other admin dependencies in your installed apps?
- Do you have `admin.autodiscover()` in your URLS.py?

Also, I think your code should look something more like this:

```
from projectname.appname.models import Appname
from django.contrib import admin


class AppnameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fieldsets = [various field sets and fields etc ]

admin.site.register(Appname,AppnameAdmin)
```

Comment: actually I believe Template_context_processors is not used in django 1.4 there was no mention of it in manage.py. after adding it I got an error message, asking  for another dependency and after adding that I got a completely empty admin page instead of the default one I got before. as I wrote in the question - admin.autodiscover() is in on and I instantiate an adminsite for the model. that's what strange about that

Comment: I don't see any reference to admin.autodiscover() in the question. Here are the 1.4 docs for template_context_processors:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
Are you able to link to the code or at least show us the files you have pasted sections from?

Comment: And it turns out that he wrote admin.py in wrong directory. :P What an answer..!

Answer (score 7):

**Have you restarted the server process?**

Maybe this helps someone: in my case the problem was solved by stopping and starting the server process, because when you add a new `admin.py` file it does not reload automatically.

Answer (score 4):

aaargghhh - I found the problem. I saved admin.py in the template/appname/ folder instead of the appname/ folder. so stupid of me. so sorry for the interruption.

Answer (score 3):

Set this in your model admin:

```
def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return True
def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return True
def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have properly added code for admin.py and models.py in your app. Make sure that your app has been added to settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    . . .
    'your_app_name.apps.Your_app_nameConfig'
]
```

After you added your app to setting.py, run following commands in your terminal:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Restart your app and see if it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Go to models.py file and add 'models.Model' as a parameter in your class .

Example:

```
class className(models.Model)
```

In your case use below as class name and it will 100% work for you.

```
class AppnameAdmin(models.Model):
```

Answer (score 0):

Check all these:

1. **Restart the server** and check again
2. Add **'models.Model'** as a parameter in your class in models.py file

```
    class Classname(models.Model):
```

3. Add your app in the 'INSTALLED_APPS' in **settings.py**, In my case it's 'travello.apps.TravelloConfig'

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'travello.apps.TravelloConfig',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ]
```

4. Add 'admin.autodiscover()' in **main** urls.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include
    admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', include('travello.urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ]
```

it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing above worked for me.

Then I went to Settings, and under Project:MyApp Project Interpreter
I switched the Project Interpreter from Python 3.8(venv) to Python 3.8(MyApp)

And then all my models where registered (could list them in `http://localhost:8000/admin/`)

Strangely enough, still in `admin.py`, after "admin.site." the method registered will not be listed as available. But it works anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import modelname
admin.site.register(modelname)
```

import models in this way

Answer (score -1):

Please consider that some models can be seen only from a superuser.
Try to create one and log-in the admin with that user.

```
python3 manage.py createsuperuser
```